# Animate svg+xml base 64 css background doesn't work in IE

Tags: css, xml, image, animation, svg

Animate svg+xml base 64 css background in IE > 9 (no care on previously version) doesn't work, work ok for Firefox and others.

Here is the background property :

background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;

If someone know why it is not animated in IE > 9 it will be great!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: On a performance related sidenote, base64 images aren't cached by the browser, so you may want to consider that when using them.

Answer (score 0):

IE does not support SMIL and so ignores the `<animate>` tags.

An up to date overview of current browser support can be found [here](http://caniuse.com/svg-smil).

Comment: Ok thank you!
So if I well understand even if I convert it in svg file it will not work!? 
I need to make this work in IE. The problem is that I need the transparency so I can't convert it in Animated gif. 
And I don't want to use CSS3...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you've painted yourself into a corner from which there is no escape with the restrictions you've provided.